# How to filter on a Partially Indexed Boolean Column in Slick?

Tags: postgresql, scala, indexing, slick

I have a Postgres DB that I am querying with Slick. The issue is that I have a BOOLEAN column (`archived`) that is indexed (partial index). I have found through EXPLAIN/ANALYZE that the index is only utilized if the query is in the form `WHERE archived IS FALSE`, however Slick only seems to output `WHERE archived = False` or `WHERE NOT archived`... How can I modify my slick query or, if that's not possible, maybe change the index so that it works with `archived = false`? Here's more info:

#### Variation 1

*Slick*

```scala
val query = Messages
  .filterOpt(isArchived) { (row, archived) => 
    if (archived) { row.archived }
    else { !row.archived }
  }
  .sortBy(_.id.desc)
```

*Slick Output*

```sql
select "id", "info", "archived" from "messages" where not "archived" order by "id" desc
```

*Query Explain*

```sql
Sort  (cost=37988.82..37988.90 rows=33 width=1033)
  Sort Key: id DESC
  ->  Seq Scan on messages  (cost=0.00..37987.99 rows=33 width=1033)
        Filter: (NOT archived)
```

#### Variation 2

*Slick*

```scala
val query = Messages
  .filterOpt(isArchived) { (row, archived) => 
    row.archived === archived
  }
  .sortBy(_.id.desc)
```

*Slick Output*

```sql
select "id", "info", "archived" from "messages" where "archived" = false order by "id" desc
```

*Query Explain (same as Explain 1)*

```sql
Sort  (cost=37988.82..37988.90 rows=33 width=1033)
  Sort Key: id DESC
  ->  Seq Scan on messages  (cost=0.00..37987.99 rows=33 width=1033)
        Filter: (NOT archived)
```

#### Variation 3

*Slick*

```scala
???
```

*Desired) Slick Output*

```sql
select "id", "info", "archived" from "messages" where "archived" IS false order by "id" desc
```

*(Desired) Query Explain*

```sql
Sort  (cost=21.67..21.75 rows=33 width=1033)
  Sort Key: id DESC
  ->  Index Scan using messages_archived on messages  (cost=0.27..20.84 rows=33 width=1033)
```

Comment: It's been years I last touched Slick, but if it still works as before this is Driver issue. The good thing is it's pretty easy to modify drivers, so if I where you I'd try to add an "is" operator to the driver.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating our partial index with `WHERE archived is false`, create it with `WHERE not archived` or `WHERE archived = false`.  Postgres seems to be smart enough to interconvert the 2nd and 3rd of those with each other, but not the first with either of the others.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this [useful Medium Article](https://medium.com/virtuslab/slick-smooth-operator-92add6d6d9ca), I found an answer. It involves extending the Slick PostgresProfile API

```scala
// ExtendedPostgresProfile.scala

import slick.ast.Library.SqlOperator
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile
import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._
import slick.lifted.BaseExtensionMethods
import scala.language.implicitConversions

/***
  * We need to Extend the PostgresProfile because the standard Slick filter on
  * `messages.archived` doesn't utilize the index on that column
  * (it uses = instead of IS). This explicitly creates an IS operator
  */
trait ExtendedPostgresProfile extends PostgresProfile {
  trait ExtApi extends API {
    implicit def extendedBoolColumn(c: Rep[Boolean]): BaseBooleanExtendedBooleanMethods[Boolean] =
      new BaseBooleanExtendedBooleanMethods[Boolean](c)
  }

  override val api: ExtApi = new ExtApi {}

  final class BaseBooleanExtendedBooleanMethods[P1](val c: Rep[P1]) extends BaseExtensionMethods[P1] {
    def is[P2, R](e: Rep[P2])(implicit om: o#arg[P1,P2]#to[P1,R]) =
      om.column(Operators.IS, n, e.toNode)
  }

  object Operators{
    val IS = new SqlOperator("IS")
  }
}

object ExtendedPostgresProfile extends ExtendedPostgresProfile
```

and the actual Slick code:

```scala
// import slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile.api._ <- Removed
import ExtendedPostgresProfile.api._

val query = Messages
  .filterOpt(isArchived) { (row, archived) => 
    row.archived is archived
  }
  .sortBy(_.id.desc)
```

output is

```sql
select "id", "info", "archived" from "messages" where "archived" IS false order by "id" desc
```